# object access in a function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, scope

This is the code:

```
(function(Info, undefined) {
    var createInfoTableForFeature = function (obj) {
        var data2form = {};
        data2form.name = obj.name;
        data2form.state = obj.state;
        data2form.stateid=obj.stateId;
        data2form.city = obj.city;
        data2form.cityId=obj.cityId;
        data2form.sector = obj.sector;
        data2form.sectorId=obj.sectorId;
        data2form.municipality = obj.municipality;
        data2form.municipalityId=obj.municipalityId;
        data2form.parish = obj.parish;
        data2form.parishId = obj.parishId; 
        data2form.postcode = obj.postcode;
    }
    Info.copy2form = function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})(window.Info = window.Info || {});
```

When I call `Info.copy2form(data2form)`, `data2form` is `undefined`

Comment: Where is Info.copy2form being called?

Comment: Where are up calling `Info.copy2form(data2form)`?  `data2form ` only exists inside `createInfoTableForFeature`.

Comment: You shouldn't use 'undefined' as a parametername.

Comment: I don't know why it would be undefined?? http://jsfiddle.net/ra4aG/1/ ,works for me (view console), you will probably find you are just calling the method before you run the code above.

Comment: inside the function createInfoTableForFeature

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [JSON](http://json.org/), so I've removed tag & buzzword.

Comment: You neither call `createInfoTableForFeature` nor `copy2form` anywhere. Why do you expect any variable to exist?

Comment: I apologize, I read the question wrong :( thought you said copy2form is undfined, rather important detail.

Comment: @EricG: The `undefined` is there to make sure that `undefined` really is `undefined` (and not overwritten).  It's just a little trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `data2form` to be global, then you'll have to remove de `var` keyword before the declaration of the variable `data2form` to make it global.

If you want to make it accesible from everywhere but within `Info` container, then you can declare it like this:

```
Info.data2form = {};
```

and then call your function like this:

```
Info.copy2form(Info.data2form)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Your post doesn't seem JSON related so far, oh well.*

Your data2form doesn't exist outside the function. You should assign it to window.data2form or define the var data2form outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because data2form is a local variable inside of the anonymous function (createInfoTableForFeature).

This is one of 1000 solutions:

```
function createInfoTableForFeature(obj) {
    var data2form = {};
    data2form.name = obj.name;

    data2form.state = obj.state;
    data2form.stateid=obj.stateId;

    data2form.city = obj.city;
    data2form.cityId=obj.cityId;

    data2form.sector = obj.sector;
    data2form.sectorId=obj.sectorId;

    data2form.municipality = obj.municipality;
    data2form.municipalityId=obj.municipalityId;

    data2form.parish = obj.parish;
    data2form.parishId = obj.parishId; 

    data2form.postcode = obj.postcode;

    return data2form;
}

var data2form = createInfoTableForFeature(obj);
Info.copy2form(data2form);
```

Comment: I assume you meant to add `return data2form;` to `createInfoTableForFeature`?